# Split two strings and pair corresponding parts

Tags: json, jq

I have this JSON:

```
{
  
  "values": [      
    {
      "type": "any",
      "value": "email1,email2,email3",
      "key": "emails"
    },
    {
      "type": "any",
      "value": "id1,id2,id3",
      "key": "ids"
    }
  ]
}
```

And I would like to have it as:

```
[
   {
      "email":"email1",
      "id":"id1"
   },
   {
      "email":"email2",
      "id":"id2"
   },
   {
      "email":"email3",
      "id":"id3"
   }
]
```

What would be the easiest way to do this with JQ? I need to reorganise it in the command line and feed the second json into another tool.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If *emails* and *ids* are fixed at the top of the array `values`, and are always in the same order, you can use this program:

```
.values | [
  (.[0].value / ","), # emails
  (.[1].value / ",")  # ids
] | transpose | map({email: .[0], id: .[1]})
```

<sup>[Online demo](https://jqplay.org/s/jLPYBbr3_E)</sup>

Otherwise, as the objects in `values` have `key`-`value` pairs, you can resort to `from_entries`:

```
.values | from_entries | [
  (.emails / ","),
  (.ids / ",")
] | transpose | map({email: .[0], id: .[1]})
```

<sup>[Online demo](https://jqplay.org/s/5WJXufOmV_)</sup>